# How do I sort users into different sized groups in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

The task here is to randomly assign a list of members to different locations that are based in around the country. Each location has a unique maximum number of members that they can accommodate.

I've got two arrays. One with a list of users, and another with a list of groups with their min / max sizes.

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [userid] => 1[name] => "luke"
    ) [1] => Array(
        [userid] => 2[name] => "peter"
    ) [2] => Array(
        [userid] => 3[name] => "joe"
    ) [3] => Array(
        [userid] => 4[name] => "mark"
    ) [4] => Array(
        [userid] => 5[name] => "bob"
    )
)
```

Imagine the array above extending for 300+ users.

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [planid] => 1[group] => 1[eventid] => 37[min] => 0[max] => 999
    ) [1] => Array(
        [planid] => 2[group] => 2[eventid] => 37[min] => 0[max] => 999
    ) [2] => Array(
        [planid] => 3[group] => 12[eventid] => 37[min] => 0[max] => 15
    ) [3] => Array(
        [planid] => 4[group] => 13[eventid] => 37[min] => 0[max] => 4
    ) [4] => Array(
        [planid] => 5[group] => 16[eventid] => 37[min] => 0[max] => 16
    ) [5] => Array(
        [planid] => 6[group] => 14[eventid] => 37[min] => 0[max] => 16
    ) [6] => Array(
        [planid] => 7[group] => 15[eventid] => 37[min] => 0[max] => 10
    )
)
```

How do I create a function that can randomly allocate users into groups, filling out the groups with a lower maximum first?

The data from the arrays is taken from a database, with a separate table storing the allocated user groups.

The desired output will inevitably be an SQL statement to store the information back into the database. But for the purposes of this post, an array would be fine.

Comment: Maybe provide a bit more context for your question. What exactly are you trying to do? What are these groups for? How do you want to present the final sorted groups (eg. array)?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need to fill from smallest maximum, until there are no users left or until groups are full, you'd first need to find the smallest maximum in the groups.

I think the solution here is to reorder you groups structure to be sorter by `max` in ascending order:

```
usort($groups, function($a, $b) {
    return $a["max"] > $b["max"];
});
```

Then you need a storage to keep your relations. In the sample here we will use an array. Let's call it `$userGroups`.

After the groups are sorted by `max` in ascending order, the group with `max = 4` comes first, then the groups with `max = 10`, etc...

So you can simply iterate over the `$groups` array. On the first iteration you hit the `groupId = 4`. Start iterating from zero to either the group maximum or the users left (`group['max'] = 4` and `users = 5`, so you will iterate to `4`)

```
$max = min($group['max'], count($users));
for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++)
```

On each iteration add the user on current index into the relational array `$userGroups` and pop one element from the array (maybe `array_pop`, `array_splice`?). This will start getting users from the first id to the last id. To achieve randomness you can `shuffle()` the array.

After it's done, 4 users will be assigned to the `groupId = 4` and one user will leave.

Then you hit the next group. The `groupId = 7`. now `min($group['max'], count($users));` will choose between `groupMax = 10` and `users = 1` which will be `min(10, 1) = 1`. So you are iterating from 0 to 1 (one iteration) and assign the only one left user to this group. The other groups will have no users.

This is the most logical scenario I can imagine. But maybe you have scenarios where one user can belong to one or more groups, then you might not need to pop anything from the array.